atomic_compare_exchange_weak/strong uncontrolled behavior
I am learning to use c11 atomic_compare_exchange_weak, and atomic_compare_exchange_strong with the following code.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile atomic_int lock = 0;

void *critical_section(void *arg) {
    int expected = 0;
    int i = 500;
    while(i--) {
        while (!atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&lock, &expected, 1));   

        printf("Thread %ld entered the critical section, lock = %d\n", (long)arg, lock);

        sleep(1);

        printf("lock = %d\n", lock);
        printf("Thread %ld leaving the critical section\n", (long)arg);
        atomic_fetch_sub(&lock, 1);
        printf("lock = %d\n\n", lock);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    if (pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, critical_section, (void *)1L) != 0) {
        perror("Failed to create thread 1");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, critical_section, (void *)2L) != 0) {
        perror("Failed to create thread 2");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

and the result is:
Thread 1 entered the critical section, lock = 1
Thread 2 entered the critical section, lock = 1
lock = 1
Thread 2 leaving the critical section
lock = 0

Thread 2 entered the critical section, lock = 1
lock = 1
Thread 1 leaving the critical section
lock = 0

what I want to do is use this atomic function to protect critical section, but have no idea about the result why both threads compare successfully.
Why two threads are able to break the while loop? and the correct way to do that? Any tips or resources will be appreciated!

Otherwise, loads the actual value pointed to by obj into *expected (performs load operation).

atomic_fetch_sub(&lock, 1); is an inefficient way to unlock.  atomic_store_explicit(&lock, 0, memory_order_release).   It doesn't need to be an RMW, and to be cheaper on x86 it doesn't need to be seq_cst.
(https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  But for testing correctness, an exchange with 0 so you can check the old value is good.
